# Selecting Periods from Pricetable

Tags: sql, ms-access

What i am trying to do is to select a price which is valid from a range  for a product.

Table:

```
create table #tblPreis
(
[Date]             date,
[Layer] int,
[Site] int,
[item] int,
[price] money
)

insert into #tblPreis
values  
    ('2015-08-19', 1, 1, 10, 0,90),
    ('2015-08-18', 1, 1, 10, 0,50),
    ('2015-08-17', 1, 1, 10, 0,50),
    ('2015-08-16', 1, 1, 10, 2,00),
    ('2015-08-15', 2, 1, 10, 2,00),
    ('2015-08-14', 1, 1, 10, 1,00),
    ('2015-08-19', 3, 1, 12, 3,00),
    ('2015-08-18', 1, 1, 9, 7,00),
    ('2015-08-17', 1, 1, 9, 8,00),
    ('2015-08-16', 1, 1, 9, 8,00),
    ('2015-08-15', 1, 1, 9, 8,00),
    ('2015-01-01', 1, 1, 9, 7,00);
```

What I would like to receive is

```
    DateStart  DateEnd      Item Price
    2015-01-01 2015-08-14   9    7,00
    2015-08-15 2015-08-17   9    8,00
    2015-08-18 2015-08-18   9    7,00
    2015-08-19 2015-08-19  12    3,00
    2015-08-14 2015-08-14  10    1,00
    2015-08-15 2015-08-16  10    2,00
    2015-08-17 2015-08-18  10    0,50
    2015-08-19 2015-08-19  10    0,90
```

As you can see the Layer and other columns beside date, item and price don't interest me.

Thank you for any advice.
Dimi

Comment: use `GROUP BY` Aggregation or `DISTINCT`: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp or https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177673.aspx

Comment: Is this really MS Access and not SQL Server?  The syntax suggests SQL Server.

Comment: are you sure your output is correct? what is the criteria for creating DateEnd column?

Comment: This should go for MS Access but i used the MSSQL syntax.

Comment: The problem with Group By and Distinct is that it does show up evry single  entry and not a time frame.

Comment: The criteria for DateEnd is only to be earlier then DateStart